# splitting an image in tkinter and context menu in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

1. I have a Python GUI in tkinter. I can chose an image and drag it around, resize, etc. What I am trying to do now is be able to split an image in a way I want; like drawing a line
   around the image I have and drawing a line that splits it.
   I am playing around with the crop method from PIL, but I am not sure how to have an interface where I can draw a line that then give coordinates to PIL's crop method to.
   Anyone have any ideas for how I can do this in tkinter?

   Here is some relevant code:

   ```
   class CreateCanvasObject(object):
    def __init__(self, canvas, image_name, xpos, ypos,tag):
     self.tag=tag
     self.canvas = canvas
     self.image_name = image_name
     self.xpos, self.ypos = xpos, ypos


     self.pil_image = PImage.open(dirpath+image_name)

     self.width=self.pil_image.size[0]
     self.height=self.pil_image.size[1]


     self.tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.pil_image)
     self.image_obj = canvas.create_image(
       xpos, ypos,anchor=NW, image=self.tk_image)



     self.move_flag = False


   class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):

     self.i=0
     self.t=0
     self.master=master

     outercanvas = Canvas(master, width=1512, height=792, bg='black')
     outercanvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True, fill=BOTH)
     self.innercanvas = Canvas(outercanvas, width=612, height=792,bg='white')
     self.innercanvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)

     self.innercanvas2 = Canvas(outercanvas, width=900, height=792,bg='blue')
     self.innercanvas2.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True)



     self.L = tk.Listbox(self.innercanvas2,selectmode=tk.SINGLE)
     self.L.pack()
     #configured listbox, deleted code here for simplicity

     self.L.bind( '<Double-Button-1>', self.insert_image)



     self.imageList = []


     #inserts an image

     def insert_image(self,event):
       imgname = self.L.get(self.L.curselection()[0])

       image_3 = CreateCanvasObject(self.innercanvas, imgname, 0, 0,self.t)
       self.t = self.t + 1
       self.imageList.append(image_3)
   ```
2. Also I was trying to add a context menu, but when I add the line:
       `self.popup_menu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)` to `class CreateCanvasObject(object)`, I get this error:

   ```
   Exception in Tkinter callback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda227\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1537, in __call__
           return self.func(*args)
       File "C:/Users/_____/PycharmProjects/untitled14/menu2.py", line 273, in insert_image
           image_3 = CreateCanvasObject(self.innercanvas, imgname, 0, 0,self.t,self)
       File "C:/Users/ASingh/PycharmProjects/untitled14/menu2.py", line 30, in __init__
           self.popup_menu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
   AttributeError: MainWindow instance has no attribute 'Menu'
   ```

Comment: This is too much code. Please read [MCVE].

Comment: Also, how are you importing tkinter? It seems like you are using both `from tkinter import *` and  `import tkinter as tk`. Your second error most likely caused by that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. That hasn't fixed it, but if I fix another issue I won't need to use a context menu yet. That'an issue with event binding. I already have the 3 mouse buttons binded to events; doing <Button-1> and <DoubleButton-1> seems to clash, so I am trying to make it so something happens from a keyboard click. So far it doesn't work.